# How to install AntTweakbar on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, importerror, ubuntu-14.04

I followed the instructions for how to install the AntTweakBar python module which I found on the AntTweakBar website (http://anttweakbar.sourceforge.net/doc/tools:anttweakbar:download)

When I try to run my code which uses this library, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 80, in <module>
    from eye import eye
  File "/home/phil/pupil-master/pupil_src/capture/eye.py", line 17, in <module>
    import atb
  File "/home/phil/pupil-master/pupil_src/shared_modules/atb/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from raw import *
  File "/home/phil/pupil-master/pupil_src/shared_modules/atb/raw.py", line 39, in <module>
    __dll__ = ctypes.CDLL(dll_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /usr/lib/libAntTweakBar.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
```

So I added a symbolic link from the AntTweakBar/src to a directory in my pupil path using

```
ln -s pwd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Thanks!

Edit:  I'm using ctypes.

Comment: Are you using `ctypes` or some sort of bindings? I didn't see any support or modules that directly use `atb`? In fact I don't think `atb` is a python module at all.... "AntTweakBar is a small and easy-to-use C/C++ library "

Comment: I updated my error - I'm using ctypes.

Comment: Have you managed to get it working without Python first? freetype-gl uses it at https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl/blob/a4cfb9abac19a0ab62b625a9b6f856e032fe3732/.travis.yml#L27 , and I've made it work on Ubuntu 15.10: https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl/issues/82#issuecomment-216025527